# Elasticsearch | filter on not related nested data

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Ok, today i have a problem to filter an elasticsearch query with double nested not related fields `specs.value.text` and `specs.spec.text`.

The mapping of these fields:

```
...
"specs": {
"type": "nested",
"properties": {
"spec": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
    "text": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},

"value": {
"type": "nested",
"properties": {
  "text": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
      "raw": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
}
}
....
```

The question is when i want to filter the query with this request:

```
    {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "and": {
              "filters": [
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "filter": {
                      "nested": {
                        "filter": {
                          "match": {
                            "specs.value.text": "10"
                          }
                        },
                        "path": "specs.value"
                      }
                    },
                    "path": "specs"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "filter": {
                      "nested": {
                        "filter": {
                          "match": {
                            "specs.spec.text": "Délai de livraison"
                          }
                        },
                        "path": "specs.spec"
                      }
                    },
                    "path": "specs"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "_source": [
        "specs"
      ]
    }
```

Elasticsearch will return document that contains the word `Délai de livraison` in `specs.spec.text` **OR** `10` in `specs.value.text`

Exemple of the result:
  First object:

```
  ...
  "specs": [
      {
        "value": [
          {
            "text": "10",
            "lang": "fr-FR"
          }
        ],
        "spec": [
          {
            "text": "Délai de livraison",
            "lang": "fr-FR"
          }
        ]
      },


      {

        "value": [
          {
            "text": "10",
            "lang": "fr-FR"
          }
        ],
        "spec": [
          {
            "text": "Volume",
            "lang": "fr-FR"
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
  ...
```

The Second Object:

```
    ...
    "specs": [
      {
        "value": [
          {
            "text": "7"
          }
        ]
        "spec": [
          {
            "text": "Délai de livraison"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct query should be the following

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "nested": {
                    "path": "specs",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "specs.value",
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [{
                                                "match": {
                                                    "specs.value.text": "10"
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "specs.spec",
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [{

                                                "match": {
                                                    "specs.spec.text": "Délai de livraison"

                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Since you were running two nested queries at specs level, so both the documents match as both the documents match each filter but in different nested documents under specs. To scope the and conditions for same nested document fire the filters under one nested query

Hope this helps
Ajay